# Плохо ли, когда много активностей?

Tags: android, android-studio

Делаю первое приложение. Некоторые задачи хотелось бы выводить в отдельные окна. Сейчас всего 3 активности, нужна 4-я.
Как вообще влияет количество активностей, плохо ли большое их количество?
Спасибо.

Comment: новая активити это полностью новая компоновка экрана и\или иная логика обработки взаимодействия с виджетами на экране, сколько у вас отличных интерфейсов, столько будет и активностей. То есть для вывода **разных**, например, новостей по одному шаблону - заголовок, картинка, текст, используется одна активити в которой меняется только контент (сам текст и картинка), а для вывода списка новостей и отображения подробностей новости - разные активити. Само количество ни на что особо не влияет (если их не сотни, конечно).

Comment: Рекомендую почитать книгу Б.Харди, Б.Филипс - Android. Программирование для профессионалов, там есть о архитектуре приложения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще, определенного ограничения нет. В идеале используйте активности только для управления фрагментами с Вашим интерфейсом. Активности лучше используйте в силу особенностей их т.н. жизненного цикла.

Comment: от фрагментов сейчас тоже отходят

Comment: @Cypher а чем тогда предлагают пользоваться?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/277289/

Comment: @Cypher "Сейчас отходят" и ссылка на статью 2016 года, которая перевод статьи 2014 года) Это я к тому, что отказаться от фрагментов пытались уже давно, но до сих пор многие их активно используют и будут продолжать, потому что если всё правильно делать, то особых проблем с ними нет.

Comment: да дофига кто уже говорил что в продакшене отказываются от них

Comment: https://android.jlelse.eu/the-dark-side-of-fragments-ca0f871b1199

Answer (score 3):

`Activity` в Андроиде аналогична странице в браузере. Когда нужно полностью сменить содержимое экрана, а по нажатию "назад" возвращать предыдущее содержимое в том же состоянии, стоит создать новую `Activity`. Если меняется только часть экрана, а остальное повторяется и в логике и в интерфейсе, то смотрите в сторону фрагментов. Если и возврат не предусмотрен и компоновка не меняется, можно просто сменить контент(текст, картинку и т.п.)